# Copy multiple files into one (append, merge) in single invocation without shell redirection?

Tags: text-processing, scripting, file-copy, cat

I'm looking for some sort of a command that I can use, to copy/append multiple files into one; but *without* shell redirection (I'd like to try it in `call_usermodehelper`, see similar issue in [call_usermodehelper / call_usermodehelperpipe usage - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143105/call-usermodehelper-call-usermodehelperpipe-usage)). I know I could otherwise use:

```
cat file1 file2 > file.merge
```

... but that requires shell redirection.

My findings so far:

- Cannot use `cat`, as it's default stdout output cannot be redefined (through, say, command line argument) - and other than that, it's shell redirection
- Cannot use `dd` in single invocation, as it can only accept one (and only one) `if=` input file argument
- Cannot use `cp`, as it will treat multiple files individually, and cannot copy them all "merged" into a single location

So - is there any standard tool, that would allow me to do something like (pseudocode):

```
copytool -i file1 -i file2 -o file.merge
```

... such that the output `file.merge` represents `file2` appended to `file1` contents?

Comment: Why not invoke a shell for the redirection?

Comment: Must it be a single command or would a sequence of commands be OK, too? Would a pipeline be OK?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - when I try to call the shell version from `call_usermodehelper` (from a timer loop in a kernel function), it seems to "skip" some calls; so for debugging purposes I wanted to try an alternative... as I'm not sure if "instantiating" a shell (and redirections) may represent too much overhead in that context, and an alternative is needed. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @HaukeLaging - I just wrote in the previous comment that I suspect the "shell instantiation" to be too slow for the kernel call context I'm trying it from - and I tried two `dd`s, and those seem to be "skipped" from my timer function call as well. Which is why I'm looking for an alternative... Cheers!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do:

```
sed -n wfile.merge file1 file2
```

Or:

```
awk '{print > "file.merge"}' file1 file2
```

Or:

```
sh -c 'cat file1 file2 > file.merge'
```

(note that depending on the implementation, the first two may not work properly with binary files).

Comment: Many thanks, @StephaneChazelas - that is the sort of syntax that I needed (unfortunately, it didn't help with my kernel calls, as they are still being skipped - but at least now I know those "skips" are not due to shell redirections). Many thanks again - cheers!